# Querying and adding date between structured tables in Excel

Tags: excel

All,

I might be asking a question that has been answered before, so please let me know if this is the case.

For my Families Business i am setting up an excel administration.
the case at hand is,

WE have a structured Excel table containing a list of clients. Some of these clients will have to be invoiced  individually and others are are invoiced though an organisation.
In my strucutred table these that have to be invoiced individually are makered (simple "YES" in column). Now i want to extract those clients whith the "Yes" into a new structured table and add invoicing details to that new 2nd table.

Any suggestions on how to do this.
Reason i do not want to have this in the 1st table is not all clients neeed individual invoicing and the first table becomes too big to interpret in one go.

Thanks for helping me.

Below the master Table

| name | Private (yes/No) | email | Date of Birth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name A | Yes | some@mail.com | 1-2-2344 |
| Name B | No | some@othermail.com | 1-2-3456 |
| Name C | Yes | some@othermail2.com | 6-5-4321 |

The result will be a new table [2]

| Name | Invoicing details | amount | Other information |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name A | details for invoicing | 100 | Ipsum |
| Name C | details for invoicing | 50 | Ipsum |
| Name etc | details for invoicing | 200 | Ipsum |

Whereby the data in column "Name" is populated automatically and the other Data is entered by hand

Comment: Try FILTER() formula.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. However i am looking for a new structured table in a second tab. i understand the filter function, however would like to link the 2 tables simular to linking 2 databases with one or 2 simular columns

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected output?

Comment: I have a table with columns A through J. these represent names and other individual information, like Personal numbers, date of birth etc. 
On of the Columns ( Column D) indicates if the service is paid privately or through a government program. This changes the invoicing 
If paid privately i'd like to select these ppl (names) and automatically create a new table with only these private paying ppl and populate this new table wit the relevent invoicing information. this information is not needed for the government clients. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes understood. Then filter formula is best approach. Refer your full table as array then apply condition to column D to include argument of filter formula.

Comment: i have added the example tables above

Comment: Try my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Select the table

Data ---> Sort ---> Sort by "X" column ---> OK

Then cut the information you need and paste it into another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

As per you sample data use below formula to sheet2

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!B:B="Yes")
```

Above formula will pull all names having Yes in Column B. Then you have to put other invoicing data manually by typing.

Comment: Thank you @harun i finally made a query from the table and added the relevant information and could in that way also filter out some coloumns